# How can I get the full path to the file I saved my code in when it is currently executing and writing out HTML for me?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I tried to make my title as direct as humanly possible.

I wrote some code, saved it in a file. I want the name of that file, and the disk path to it, at the moment it runs. This is for a website, and I have access to `HttpContext`.

I wrote some code in a Razor file. I put that file on my IIS website, and it got executed by some convoluted hierarchy steps with partials and the like. I want to write some code that spits out the path to that file.

I don't want to hard-code the filename and its current path in my code. I want to copy the magic piece of code I'm asking for here onto lots of other Razor pages, so each time I can spit out a comment in some **script** or **style** tag somewhere so that other developers can track down my <s>mistakes</s> amazing work.

I don't want to know how the end-user's browser got to my file. I'd use `Server.MapPath` or `Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"]` if I wanted that.

I don't want to know merely what directory my website app is running in. I'd use `HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath` for that.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you give an example because I don't understand what the path is you are looking for.

Comment: @VDWWD - E.g., my code file is "D:\Website\Folder\Subfolder\MyFile.cshtml" and it helps render my webpage at "http://myhost.example.com/app/items/my_web_page". I want code to obtain the string "D:\Website\Folder\Subfolder\MyFile.cshtml" for me.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a line of code that can do that. But with `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` and [ViewContext](http://www.dotnet-tutorials.net/Article/get-current-controller-and-action-name-in-a-view) you could get it I think.

Comment: @VDWWD - I see where you're going but that's not really it. That will show the URL that was used to access the page that's being rendered. The file as it exists on my webserver might be in a completely different location.

Plus, Razor files can make `@helper` functions in auxiliary files, then use those helpers on the main Razor page (the one accessed via the URL). I'm trying to get the auxiliary file path and name.